# Different ways of calling a PHP class

Tags: php, class

When you call a PHP class - for the sake of example I will call the class `myClass` and give it a method called `someMethod()`
What is the difference between the following ways of calling it.

```
$AAA = new myClass();
$AAA->someMethod();
```

and

```
myClass::someMethod();
```

and

```
$AAA = 'myClass';
$AAA::someMethod();
```

Comment: The 1st one calls `someMethod` on a *specific instance* of `myClass`.  The last 2 call `someMethod` statically.

Comment: Here is some more information on [PHP static keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: Read [TFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and especially [the basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) vs [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's clarify the vernacular. Classes get *instantiated*, methods get *called*, so you would say "ways of calling a method", instead of "ways of calling a class".

Now, the answer to your question lies in the above clarification: Classes get instantiated, and what you get when you do that is an Object (or Object Instance, or Instance). This instance has both Methods and Data.

A Class (not an instantiation of the class) has methods. Some of these methods require that they only be called on Instances (that is, they require or use *instance data*, for example using `$this` in the method body). Some methods may not have such a requirement, and can therefore be declared as [Static Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). Static methods (other languages may call them "Class Methods") are invokable directly from the class and have no relationship to an "Instance", which in PHP means they do not have a `$this` variable when you invoke them. But they do have a `self` keyword which refers to the class on which the method was invoked.

The syntax varies in PHP between calling an instance method and a static method:

```
$obj->instanceMethod();
ObjClass::staticMethod();
```

You may find it interesting that this is only a *style* decision by PHP, and that other languages have identical syntax for calling class vs. instance methods. Here is an Objective-C example:

```
[myInstance setFoo:bar];
[MyClass fooMethodWithArg:bar];
```

Comment: +1 for saying its just a cosmetic thing because PHP makes no sense at all